# Clipp both axes of a scatter plot at 99% quantiles to exclude outliers in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, quantile

I have a large data frame. I would like to create a scatter plot where visual outliers are clipped in both axes at 99% quantiles.

```
   A     B
a  1     2999
b  700   2
c  665   6
d  1778  3
e  4     4890
```

This is how it looks after plotting A vs B.

[image]

Comment: You can do it manually with `plot(A~B, ylim=c(0,5000), xlim=c(0,5000))` if you are willing to guesstimate the outliers.

Comment: you could also consider plotting on a different scale, for example log transformed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Plot on a logaritmic scale, i.e.:

```
plot(x = A, y = B, log="xy")
```

**Option 2**

You can use the `quantile()` function:

```
quant_a <- quantile(A, 0.99)
quant_b <- qunatile(B, 0.99)

plot(x = A, y = B, xlim = c(0,quant_a), ylim = c(0, quant_b))
```